# sumproduct 2 dataframes with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sumproduct

Have 2 dataframes df['x'] and df['y'].
How do i multiply the 2 tables and sum the rows?

```
x0  x1  x2      y0  y1  y2
2   5   9       2   3   4
Nan 4   7       2   2   3
3   Nan 3       1   2   3
```

Desired output:
(2x2)+(5x3)+(9x4) = 55
etc..

Nan should be treated as 0.
I keep hitting results with nan values with the below code.
Any other more efficient ways to solve this?

```
df['z'] = (df['x'].to_numpy() * df['y'].to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: What should happen when you encounter `NaN`? What should be result for second row?

Comment: Without alteraing original values, Nan should be treated as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas supports [arithmetic operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html#pandas.DataFrame.mul) over dataframe, and also provides flexible wrappers for them.

```
 df.method()   operator
------------------------
     add          +
     sub          -
     mul          *
     div          /
     mod          %
     pow          **
```

Simply multiply the original dataframe with nan values filled.

```
#METHOD 1
(df_x.fillna(0)*df_y.values).sum(1)
```

Or you can use `pd.DataFrame.mul()` which is equivalent to `*` but provides the functionality of adding `fill_value`

```
#METHOD 2
df_x.mul(df_y.values, fill_value=0).sum(1)
```

```
0    55.0
1    29.0
2    12.0
dtype: float64
```

> **Note:** If `df_y` as nan values as well, then replace `df_y.values` with `df_y.fillna(0).values`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `filter` with the `regex` argument:

```
df.filter(regex='x\d').mul(df.filter(regex='y\d').to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)
```

Or only with `filter(like=...)`:

```
df.filter(like='x').mul(df.filter(like='y').to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
0    55.0
1    29.0
2    12.0
dtype: float64
```